# prevent multiple sound files from overlapping as played

Tags: ios, audio

I have a simple question: I found a way to stop a file from playing when a second file is played back, so that they do not overlap. Now my question is, how about applying this methoid to, for instance, 7 files without making the statement too long ?

```
- (IBAction)playSound1 {
if (self.sound2Player.playing)
    [self.sound2Player stop];
[self.sound1Player play];
 }

 - (IBAction)playSound2 {
if (self.sound1Player.playing)
    [self.sound1Player stop];
[self.sound2Player play];
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of different ways you could potentially solve this problem.

The first one that comes to mind is keep a local variable that is the currently playing sound.

```
- (IBAction)playSound1 {
    if (self.playingSoundPlayer != nil) {
        [self.playingSoundPlayer stop];
    }
    self.playingSoundPlayer = self.sound1Player;
    [self.sound1Player play];
}
```

You could get fancy and make sure you set the playingSoundPlayer to nil when your sound finishes playing, but it probably won't hurt anything to call stop again, so it's sort of up to you.

Comment: Thank you, I will cgeck it out as soon as possible !